# How to get real value from log adjustement value

Tags: biostatistics, logarithm, scatterplot

I am looking for some data for my research, and found reliable graph which showed the correlation of fetal weight and gestational age which is what I want. However, the weight in that scatter plot graph was not real/absolute value. It was shown in Log (weight). I am not very good at statistics, and I am wondering how can I get real weight value from that log value in that scatter plot graph. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the numbers from the graph, how to convert from log(weight) to weight, or both?

Comment: I am asking how to convert from log(weight) to weight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which base the log was to.

If it's a natural log (base $e$), you exponentiate (i.e. $w=\exp(\log_e(w)) = e^{\log_e(w)}$).

If it's a base 10 log (common log), you raise 10 to the power of it ($w=10^{\log_{10}(w)}$).